# Why does this error message Comes alongside Another one?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!);
```

(I KNOW THE RULES BUT WANT TO KNOW WHY THE COMPILER COMPLAINED)

This produces two different error messages, even though there is only one
underlying syntax error:

First Message:-

```
Hello.java:3: unclosed string literal <br>
System.out.println("Hello, world!);
```

Another message:-

```
Hello.java:4: ')' expected before }
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Hello, world!);` this is wrong you cannot pass string like this in print method. you should use `System.out.println("Hello, world!");`

Comment: I know that, I mean, I got the rules inside me, But Why would the compiler say ")" expected. Cause I have put that....  However Thanks and "HAPPY CODE"

Comment: @AmitraksharBiszz Because the compiler ignored your `)` because it thinks it is part of the string. See my answer. Did it help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't have a closing `"`. That's what the first error message tells you, but I guess you are more interested in why the second message appears.

Because you missed a `"`, everything after the `"` is treated as a string:

```
Hello, world!);
```

You will see that the `)` is also treated as part of the string, so that's why the compiler couldn't find a `)`.

Fun fact: doing this:

```
System.out.println("Hello World
        ); // note the new line
```

will make the second message disappear but not the first one. This is because string literals cannot span multiple lines. The compiler finds an unenclosed string literal, hence the first message, but it *can* find a `)` this time, so no second message.

Comment: Sorry, I checked but Before I have checked the I got distracted from the world of INTERNET and was disconnected for about 6 hours as my country does not provide a GOOD service of INTERNET!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!);
//First error as your expectations you didn't closed string literal using ".   
//Second error because you didn't enclosed your string in " and " then compiler took ');' as part of string and hence it saying you you missed ')' before '}'.

//Replace your line with below lines

    //START
    System.out.println("Hello, world!);

    ; 
    //END
//When you replace your line with my code given where ';' represent line end then you will get only first error.
```